# Recyclerview is not displayed in fullscreen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Recyclerview is not displayed in fullscreen. Below is the layout file and the code I've written. After executing, the contents are displayed as shown in the below picture. The height is only the highlighted part. I want the contents to be fullscreen. **I remaining contents are within this highlighted area which is scrollable**. I want the contents to be displayed in fullscreen. Any help would be helpful.

[image]

*Layout file:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_search"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```java
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.List;

    public class setSearchData extends RecyclerView.Adapter<setSearchData.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<SearchDisplayContents> moviesList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView title, year, genre;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
                year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_searchresults, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            SearchDisplayContents movie = moviesList.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
            holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
            holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }
    }
```

Calling function code:

```java
     List<SearchDisplayContents> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        setSearchData mAdapter = new setSearchData(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        SearchDisplayContents movie = new SearchDisplayContents("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new SearchDisplayContents("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: please show the whole layout file

Comment: The layout file is complete. Please check

Comment: Please show us: activity_searchresults.xml

Comment: The above layout file is activity_searchresults.xml itself

Comment: So clearly, you should use different layout for your viewholder. Take the RelativeLayout you have there, cut it out, put it in different xml file then pass it to onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: It is working now, after putting the RelativeLayout into different file. Thanks xklakoux

Comment: Then please accept my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different layout for your viewholder. Take the RelativeLayout you have there, cut it out, put it in different xml file then pass it to onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: I've tried that as well, if it is match_parent, the screen gets full view but no contents are displayed

Answer (score 0):

You should use different layout for your viewholder. Take the RelativeLayout you have there, cut it out, put it in different xml file then pass it to onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: Sorry, I edited your answer by mistake and couldn't undo it. Someone accepted it, though, no idea why

Answer (score 0):

From look at your code - it looks like what is in the preview screenshot is the same as what is within the RelativeLayout you have staticly defined.

There is an issue with your approach. It is that you are referencing the RelativeLayout (within the same xml hierarchy as your RecylerView) as the CellViewHolder in the RecyclerView.Adapter. My approach personally is to create a seperate xml layout for the cell viewholder.

Follow this guide, it is very detailed:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

The above coding has something work **use different layout mean one for Recycleview and other for contents in list**

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/uslist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_49sdp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter.java

```
public class yourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder> {


ArrayList<UsageRPDetails> mylist;
private Context mContext;

public yourAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<yourArray or model> checklist) {
    mContext = context;
    mylist = checklist;
}

@Override
public yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
    return new yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final yourAdapter .SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.title.setText();
    holder.year.setText();
    holder.genre.setText();


}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mylist.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.title)
    TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.genre)
    TextView genre;
@Bind(R.id.year)
    TextView year;


    public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        genre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);


    }
}
```

}

Also write  a java file for Activity that calls this adapter class and call the recycleview in this activity